# Base protocol (https://) for every render/redirect_to call

Tags: ruby, https, protocols, render, redirecttoaction

is there a way i can set up a base protocol to use

```
render :action => "myaction"
redirect_to :action => "myaction"
```

instead of calling

```
render :action => "myaction", :protocol => "https://"
redirect_to :action => "myaction", :protocol => "https://"
```

every time?

Answer (score -1):

Simply use config.force_ssl = true in your environment configuration.

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = true
  end
end
```

You can also selectively enable https depending on the current Rails environment. For example, you might want to keep HTTPS turned off on development, and enable it on staging/production.

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.force_ssl = false
  end
end

# config/environments/production.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```

Behind the scenes, Rails adds the awesome Rack::SSL Rack middleware to your application middleware stack. Rack::SSL automatically filters the request, redirects not-HTTPS requests to the corresponding HTTPS path and applies some additional improvements to make sure your HTTPS request is secure.

Comment: @mzjn thanks for your comment. I just updated answer accordingly. Keep up the good work.